# "different prefix" error and "Lockfile is unreadable" error when pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, error-handling, heroku-cli

I've recently made some updates to a Ruby on Rails Heroku app that was working fine. I tried updating the bundler version so that it could be configured with a datadog agent. Now when I try to push to heroku master I get the following error:

```html
git push heroku master
Counting objects: 28, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (28/28), done.
Writing objects: 100% (28/28), 3.33 KiB | 1.66 MiB/s, done.
Total 28 (delta 19), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> ActiveStorage Preview app detected
remote: -----> Installing binary dependencies for ActiveStorage Preview
remote:        Downloading packages..
remote:        Installing packages.....
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     different prefix: "" and "/tmp/build_2f915e77052b7fa5cef9531ffdd277e6"
remote:  !
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.5.0/pathname.rb:522:in `relative_path_from': different prefix: "" and "/tmp/build_2f915e77052b7fa5cef9531ffdd277e6" (ArgumentError)
remote:  from /tmp/d20190215-459-drze92/bundler-1.15.2/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:98:in `rescue in initialize'
remote:  from /tmp/d20190215-459-drze92/bundler-1.15.2/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:61:in `initialize'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:130:in `new'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:130:in `block in parse_gemfile_lock'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:86:in `instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:128:in `parse_gemfile_lock'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:112:in `lockfile_parser'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:74:in `specs'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:59:in `block in gem_version'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:86:in `instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:58:in `gem_version'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails5.rb:9:in `block in use?'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/rails5.rb:8:in `use?'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in detect'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack.rb:16:in `each'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack.rb:16:in `detect'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack.rb:16:in `block in detect'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack.rb:13:in `detect'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/bin/support/ruby_compile:17:in `block in <main>'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `block in trace'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/bin/support/ruby_compile:15:in `<main>'
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: ! Push rejected to codereader-backend.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/codereader-backend.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs
```

Before this error I was getting an error about the my lockfile is unreadable. I removed the lockfile and rebundled to no avail.That error is below.

```html
git push heroku master
Counting objects: 27, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (27/27), done.
Writing objects: 100% (27/27), 3.24 KiB | 1.62 MiB/s, done.
Total 27 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> ActiveStorage Preview app detected
remote: -----> Installing binary dependencies for ActiveStorage Preview
remote:        Downloading packages..
remote:        Installing packages.....
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Your lockfile is unreadable. Run `rm Gemfile.lock` and then `bundle install` to generate a new lockfile.
remote:  !
remote: /tmp/d20190215-478-1u5qan1/bundler-2.0.1/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:98:in `rescue in initialize': Your lockfile is unreadable. Run `rm Gemfile.lock` and then `bundle install` to generate a new lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)
remote:  from /tmp/d20190215-478-1u5qan1/bundler-2.0.1/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:61:in `initialize'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:130:in `new'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:130:in `block in parse_gemfile_lock'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:  from /tmp/tmp.f4TZaBjbzE/lib/ruby/2.4.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:86:in `instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:128:in `parse_gemfile_lock'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:112:in `lockfile_parser'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:74:in `specs'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:59:in `block in gem_version'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:  from /tmp/tmp.f4TZaBjbzE/lib/ruby/2.4.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:86:in `instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/helpers/bundler_wrapper.rb:58:in `gem_version'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/rails5.rb:9:in `block in use?'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:  from /tmp/tmp.f4TZaBjbzE/lib/ruby/2.4.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/rails5.rb:8:in `use?'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in detect'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack.rb:16:in `each'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack.rb:16:in `detect'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack.rb:16:in `block in detect'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:  from /tmp/tmp.f4TZaBjbzE/lib/ruby/2.4.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack.rb:13:in `detect'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/bin/support/ruby_compile:17:in `block in <main>'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `block in trace'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
remote:  from /tmp/tmp.f4TZaBjbzE/lib/ruby/2.4.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
remote:  from /app/tmp/buildpacks/19b20846a186a4065aa6710b809d0c465ff7a2235264402d06b5038f9562c56867a32c308dd2410d96108925a9f9fed74b5ef871dd6514a3a3a5485da3f442cf/bin/support/ruby_compile:15:in `<main>'
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: ! Push rejected to codereader-backend.
remote:
```

Any help is appreciated.I'm not sure what steps to take and there aren't any similar errors that I've found.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could be merge conflicts in the Gemfile.lock. Try running `bundle install` locally and see if it works before committing and pushing to heroku.